# Plugin grails to consume web service with property id

Tags: web-services, grails, grails-plugin

Good morning everyone.

I am developing a plugin for my project which will consuimir a web service in the system and my question is how to have a general standard of access where each user has an ID registered in the database, giving you access to the API that will be consumed.

Example DB:

User 1 - Name, API_KEY ... 
User 2 - Name, API_KEY ...

My question is what is the best way to get these values​​, leaving my unbound plugin for my whole system, and can even be reused by others. At first a bean that receives configuration via constructor parameters:

```
class ExpediaConfiguration implements Configuration {

    private final String cid;
    private final String apiKey;
    private final String minorRev;
    private final String customerSessionId;
    private final String customerIpAddress

    public ExpediaConfiguration(String cid, String apiKey, String minorRev, String customerSessionId, String customerIpAddress) {

          //do some

    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Maybe he receive the Properties were more interesting?

But I'm not sure this is the ideal implementation, perhaps the Spring help me more but do not know how.

I appreciate the answers.

Comment: Is this going to be a bean or a service?

Comment: This is just a bean to configure a config user, i have a service that made calls to another web service.